# Navigating through the vc revisions of a file

Tags: git

There is any command/package that allows me to move back and forth through the vc history of a file, updating the buffer to display the previous/next revision of that file?

Let's say I have a file with 3 commits/versions, and I'm viewing the current "version 3" of the file.  Then using the `go-back` and `go-fwd` commands should work like this:

- `go-back` -> update buffer with version 2
- `go-back` -> update buffer with version 1
- `go-fwd`  -> update buffer with version 2

etc...

Comment: Please write more clearly, without using needless abbreviations or meaningless phrases like "between the git log" (between the git log and *what*? Did you even mean the git log?!).

Comment: feels hard to be more clear. between versions. btw 1 & 2 , 2 & 3 etc

Comment: Then please compare https://emacs.stackexchange.com/posts/79784/revisions for future reference.  Clarity is everything when you're asking questions.  You should *want* to ensure that your question is as easily-comprehensible as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give [git-timemachine](https://codeberg.org/pidu/git-timemachine) a try.

According to the `Commentary` section of the package it may do what you are after:

```
;;; Use git-timemachine to browse historic versions of a file with p
;;; (previous) and n (next).
```

Comment: seems what Im seeking. ty !

Comment: Nice. If so, please mark the answer as accepted so to help other readers in the future.